# Matrix initialization at matlab with fixed number of randomly distributed integers

Tags: matlab, matrix, initialization

I want to fill a 100x100 matrix at matlab with ,say, 100 1s,550 2s,700 3s,50 4s that will be randomly positioned at the matrix.I am having trouble doing that.Can you help?

Comment: Providing requirements without showing any effort was once considered [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It is still [being debated now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215596/are-code-questions-without-an-attempt-now-on-topic), and many people consider it to be rude.

Comment: create a giant vector of those numbers, do a random permutation and reshape

Comment: It's a simple random variable. Turn to your textbook please.

Answer (score 4):

```
x = [ones(1,100) 2*ones(1, 550) 3*ones(1, 700) 4*ones(1, 50)]; % desired elements
x = [x zeros(1, 100*100 - length(x))]; % zero the rest
x = x(randperm(10000)); % randomly permute
x = reshape(x, 100, 100); % reshape into matrix
```